# Validation is not working with material ui textinput

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, validation, material-ui

I want to do setState with validation like value is less than 25 and greater than 1, empty is allowed but characters should not allow. Want to add only numbers from 1 to 24.

```
function handleChangeWithoutMinusandDecimal(e) {
const re = /^[0-9\b]+$/;
const isNumber = re.test(e.target.value) ? true : false;
// console.log(isNumber);
if (
  (e.target.value > 0 && e.target.value < 25 && isNumber) ||
  e.target.value === ""
) {
  // console.log("hi" + e.target.value);
  setState({
    ...state,
    [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
  });
}
```

}

Don't know what's wrong but with this, I can add characters too. Kindly, suggest.

Comment: simple question but why is there a '\b' in the regex ? and why do you reasign a boolean for isNumber while re.test() return the same boolean ?

Comment: not necessary @Leyffda but to check what's went wrong I tried out that way for double sure. but it's returning boolean. you can go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<TextField/>` component and pass `type='number'` to it.